# What is the preferred way of passing data of varying size between DLLs?

Tags: c++, .net, serialization, dll

## TL;DR

I need to pass structures of data with irregular sizes between native DLLs and between native DLLs and .NET assemblies. I'm searching for a way of doing that with minimum effort and in a way which minimizes possible bugs. Since however it will happen rarely, it may be at a cost of performance (in terms e.g. 500ms is fine although perfectly I'd like to get lower times).

## Background

I'm implementing modular application in .NET, which will use P/Invoke to communicate with native DLLs (these will be modular). The architecture I'm thinking about (WIP) is:

```
+-----------------------+        +----------------+        +---------------------+
| .NET/WPF application  | 1    1 | Native DLL     | 1    * | Native DLLs         |
+-----------------------+ <----> +----------------+ <----> +---------------------+
|          GUI          |        | Interface to   |        | Module with various |
+-----------------------+        | native modules |        | responsibilities    |
                                 +----------------+        +---------------------+
```

Upon startup the interface-DLL will query all modules and request some information. The results will vary in size (roughly it will be an array of structures containing, among others, text of varying size). This data will then be passed to the .NET application, which will serve as a central point for all processing.

It is possible that .NET application will also send structures varying in size to the native DLLs (a variable size tree with nodes being structures with text and images of varying sizes). I'm unsure if I'll follow this path, but it is still likely.

I'm looking for a way of exchanging such data. In warm and cozy world of .NET it is simple, because one can pass `List<T>`s with `string`s, byte arrays etc. - since classes, strings and arrays are part of the CLR, all .NET assemblies would correctly "decode" passed information.

In C++ it is not as easy though - I'm taking into consideration, among others, different runtimes, different compilers etc. - attempting to pass "classes by value" would be a risky thing to do.

For now I'm considering the following options (bare in mind that I'm only occasionally writing in C++ - that's why I'm asking):

### Binary serialization

Long story short: DLL A serializes data into a well-known binary format, passes a pointer to beginning of data along with its length to DLL B and the latter decodes the data into its own set of structures and classes. The same can be done between DLL B and .NET assembly.

Upsides:

- Relatively simple implementation
- Binary compatibility is relatively simple to achieve (given fixed endian-ess of numbers and encoding of text).

Downsides:

- Bug prone: it is easy to introduce hard to detect bug (e.g. in rarely used field)
- Requires double implementation: one in C++, one in .NET (and keeping those compatible)
- Having forward/backward compatibility requires additional, manual implementation (unless I use a library for serialization/deserialization like e.g. Google's Protobuf)

### Using some intermediary text format

Long story short: DLL A serializes data into JSON/XML, DLL B deserializes data into classes/structures. Passing data from DLL to .NET is as easy.

Upsides:

- Working with JSON and XML in .NET is a charm
- Relatively easily achievable forwards/backwards compatibility

Downsides:

- Noticeably slower than binary serialization
- Working on JSON in C++ is harder than in .NET (?)

## My question:

Which of the before-mentioned methods is a go-to one in native C++ world in terms of ease of implementation, backward/forward compatibility and reliability? Is there a different way which I didn't consider? (maybe COM?)

Comment: You have to copy.  .NET objects are fundamentally incompatible with C++ data requirements, the garbage collector moves them around.  Pinning them very rapidly gets impractical.  Sure, protobuf was made for this.

Comment: Why do you need these native DLLs anyway, can they not be written in pure C#?

Comment: Considered using a DB like SQLite? You can store data in relational database.

Comment: @HansPassant, I can safely assume that data will be consumed upon returning control to the caller. I suppose the marshaling magic should keep the passed memory chunk in place for that time? And also I have just figured that protocols for some of the calls will be only known at run-time - in that case I guess I'm condemned to implement my own serialization mechanism or don't I?